# Print_area name conflict excel-2007 Add-ins VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto, excel-addins, shared-addin

I have developed Excel-2007 Add-Ins using vb.net. and its working fine. but when we open the older sheet created using this add ins it shows the "Print_Area Name conflict" error. plz can any one suggest how i solve this issue. screen shot attached.

[image: Error Image]

Thanks

Mitesh

Answer (score 1):

I found a [discussion on the Excel Google discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.excel/browse_thread/thread/334f99250d0461a9/40b47c0fb3b18a0c?#40b47c0fb3b18a0c) which describes your problem, as well as a way to address it. The source of the problem is that the Workbook contains a user defined range named "Print_Area", which is one of the range names that Excel itself uses and manages by default.

Comment: But its not working for me. bcoz i am using excel add ins. When open file it shows that dialog box. but i do not want to show this dialog box. why this dialog box appeared.

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you work with your excel, this can still hit you (as it just did). I loaded a German Excel file into an Excel MS365 set up with the *English Display option*. The cure: Start your excel using another *Office Display language* which must be changed in Word. After that you will most likely be able to load the file, open the data manager, and delete or rename the reserved names, then you can revert to your preferred *Display Language*. The same may apply if this happens for another language.